# Find only equal words in list exist in string

Tags: c#, string, list

I have several lists, with words content about 2000-3000 words:

```
var list1 = new List<string> {"able", "adorable", "adventurous", ...};
```

and than if  string `inputStr = "do, dream";` contains any value from list, I want, look for each word in string into `string[] words = inputStr.Split(' '); foreach (string word in words)` with `if (list1.Any(word.Contains))`.

I'm not sure, maybe it is because I use list, or my search `Contains` method is not correct for this case, but in result I found words, which is not equal to words exist in input string, but which contains this words as part of word, for example for word "do" or word "dream":

```
(do)      adorable, doubt, fully, do, doh, freedom, down, double
(dream)   dreamily, dream
```

Not sure how to avoid this, maybe better use `Dictionary` or `SortedDictionary` if problem is list. Same result I have if I check it this way  `var val1 = list1.FirstOrDefault(stringToCheck => stringToCheck.Contains(word));` Seems like different search gives me same results with list, all words which contains found words in input string as part of word, but desired result is to find only equal words:

```
(do)      do
(dream)   dream
```

Comment: Seems like you want to do `list1.Contains(word)`.

Comment: What is your final goal? You want to find words in text which present in your `list1`?

Comment: Sounds like you can get what you want with making the input a list and then getting `list1.Intersect(list2)`

Comment: @juharr Hello, I have answered about results to galister below if i write  (list1.Contains(word)) instead (list1.Any(word.Contains)), not sure about reason

Comment: @Sergey Berezovskiy  Hello, exactly. I think tonythewest answer is useful for my particular case

Comment: @ Forklift  Hello, not sure if I completely understand, what is  advantage for my case if I use list1.Intersect(list2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IndexOf()` method will get you the index of any equivalent strings within the collection.

You could also do something like this with LINQ:

```
list.Any(x => x == "testString");
```

Comment: Hello, I found this way as most useful for my case, so I'm going to mark it as answer, but in case of  such input as var input = new string[] { "text" };  m.rogalski answer is useful

Answer (score 2):

To find the sequence that contains your "word" you should use `Linq` :

```
// (do)      adorable, doubt, fully, do, doh, freedom, down, double
var result = list1.Select(word => word.Contains("do"));
```

But if you're trying to get word that matches fully :

```
var result = list1.Select(word => word.Equals("do"));
```

Combining this with your input list :

```
var result = input.SelectMany(x => list1.Where(w => w.Equals(x)));
```

**EDIT:**

[Here you can check it online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aiaZyK)

Comment: Hello, yes that's useful for such input as var input = new string[] { "do", "doh", "no" }; in my case I use just string

Answer (score 1):

You can get it done with a single Linq line:

```
List<string> list1 = new List<string> { "able", "adorable", "adventurous" };
string inputstr = "the adorable adventurous cat";
var found_words = inputstr.Split(' ').Where(word => list1.Contains(word));
// found_words[0] = "adorable"
// found_words[1] = "adventurous"
```

Comment: @nikorio IEnumerable collections do not implement indexing. You can simply add .ToArray() or .ToList() at the end of code to cast 'found_words' to an string[] or List<string> type, both of which can handle indexing.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (list1.Contains(word))
```

Will only match whole exact strings in list.

But in that case, you should make list1 a HashSet instead, that will have much better performance.

Comment: Hello, well I tried this way also, I'm not sure why, but this way (list1.Contains(word)) instead (list1.Any(word.Contains))  result is also specific, there are no more words which contains string words as part of word, and it finds equals, but also finds absolutely non existent words. For example, if list does not contains word even as a part of any other word, and my input string is "android", but it says that's the list contains word "android". I don't trying to extract word from list, just want know if contains

Answer (score 0):

Linq is still your best bet.  Assuming you want case sensitivity but don't want to observe hanging whitespace:

```
public string Foo(string input, List<string> list)
{
    return (list.FirstOrDefault(t.Trim() == input.Trim())); 
}
```

I personally prefer to compare `strings` by value than using `Equals` most of the time, though for string comparisons you may want to narrow down `Culture` as necessary..

Comment: Hello, it is looks useful for different case, but I'm not quite understand advantage for my particular case?